# Finding the path in a graph with the least casualties according to the lanchester square law

Tags: java, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I'm trying to find the best possible path in graph using Bellman-Ford algorithm. However, instead of using the sum of all edges to calculate the path length, I want the path with the least casualties. We calculate casualties using this formula: `remainingSoldiers = sqrt(a^2 - b^2)`, where A is our army, B is the enemy army and remainingSoldiers is the number of our soldiers left after the fight.

An example: Let's say we want to conquer city D. We are starting in vertex A with army of strength 100. Our army travels to vertex B, which is patrolled by an enemy army of strength 50. According to our formula, we have 86 soldiers left. Next our army travels to vertex C, so our 86 soldiers fight with 40 soldiers patrolling vertex C, and we have 76 soldiers left. And finally, our 76 soldiers travel to vertex D which is being guarded by 70 enemy soldiers. According to our formula, we conquered the vertex D with 29 soldiers.

So in order to find the best path, we have to calculate which path to take in order to have the least casualties. Hint I got is to set the strength of our army and the strength of the enemy army as weights of edges and use the Bellman-Ford with a modified relaxation algorithm to find the best find path. That's exactly what I did in my code below.

I realized that in order to find the best path, I must find the path with the lowest number of casualties, not the highest number of soldiers left, since finding the path with the highest number is a NP-complete problem.

My code is following (I'm using a custom library for graphs, but it should be really straight-forward and easy to understand):

```
public Map<Vertex, Double> bellmanFord(Vertex s) {
            Map<Vertex, Double> d = g.createVertexMap(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
            d.put(s, 0d);
            for (int i = 0; i < g.getVertices().size(); i++)
                    for (Edge e : g.getEdges())
                            relax(e, d);
            return d;
    }

    public void relax(Edge e, Map<Vertex, Double> d) {
            Vertex u = e.getSource();
            Vertex v = e.getTarget();
            if (d.get(u) + e.getWeight() < d.get(v))
                    d.put(v, d.get(u) + e.getWeight());
    }
```

And below is my modified code for the relaxation:

```
    public void relax(Edge e, Map<Vertex, Double> d) {
            Vertex u = e.getSource();
            Vertex v = e.getTarget();
            if (d.get(u) - formula(g.getEdge(u, v).getWeight(), g.getEdge(v, u).getWeight()) > d.get(v))
                d.put(v, d.get(u) - formula(g.getEdge(u, v).getWeight(), g.getEdge(v, u).getWeight()));
    }

    public double formula(double ourCity, double enemyCity) {
            double a = Math.pow(ourCity, 2);
            double b = Math.pow(enemyCity, 2);
            double result = a - b;
            return Math.sqrt(result);
    }
```

However, my code is outputting a total nonsense. Could you help me fix my problem and implement the formula inside the method relaxation for the Bellman-Ford algorithm?

This is graph I'm launching my code with (not an edge case, just a random graph to test basic functionality): https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK5xB.png . We are trying to conquer the city H from the city A. Our army of strength 120 is located in the city A . When running my modified code, the bellman-ford outputs the following: `{a=Infinity, d=Infinity, f=Infinity, g=Infinity, b=Infinity, c=Infinity, h=Infinity, e=Infinity}.`I think I have to somehow modify the edges representing the strength of my army as my algorithm goes (I can use method .setWeight() on any edge..), but unsure how to implement it. I tried many variations of the relaxation, but none got close to the correct answer so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show any input/output so we can have a better approximation of what is going wrong.

Comment: @ZainArshad Hi, I edited my post with an image of my example graph, explanation of the graph and the output.

Comment: return Math.sqrt(vysledok) - what's vysledok ? That 'formula' method doesn't use 'result' ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew ooops, sorry. Vysledok = result.. It was missing a translation - fixed it now.

Comment: @BrianAgnew its slovak word for "result"

Comment: Aren't all the nodes connected to each other ? in the image its like only two paths ... plus, a value on edge means the number of soldiers in that city like city c = 20, b =10 ?

Comment: @ZainArshad Basically the input may be any graph, what I did is just some random graph to test basic functionality. And yes, instead of saving strength of armies in each city in something like a Map, I'm instead setting it as weight of an edge. For an example, edge B-A has weight 10, which means that in vertex B is located army of 10 soldiers. Saving it this way instead of Map may make it easier to rewrite bellman-ford, I think.

Comment: @MartinN. I once written a bellman-ford for assignment let me change it and see if it works ... wait ....

Comment: @MartinN. cant you just find the shortest path with least number of enemy soldiers(without reducing your soldiers) and after that having the path you will just apply your sqrt(a^2-b^2) formula while displaying the result

Comment: @ZainArshad I thought of that too, but I think there would be some counterexamples, since sometimes a path with higher number of enemy soldiers may be better. For an example, our army may defeat a huge enemy army only if we tackle them from the start (when our unit count is still high). If some path has a lower overall number of enemy soldiers, but a huge number of soldiers near the end of the path, we may not be able to defeat them. Do you understand?

Comment: Let `A` be the initial amount of soldiers. Remaining soldiers, squared, after the first encounter: `R1^2 = A^2 - B1^2`. After second encounter: `R2^2 = R1^2 - B2^2 = A^2 - B1^2 - B2^2`. After k encounters: `Rk^2 = A^2 - B1^2 - ... - Bk^2`. So, it's essentially shortest part problem... But you have to square your edge weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three problems with your code:

1. Storing your starting force in the graph creates ambiguity since you can't tell whether this edge has your forces or enemy's forces as weight. This will be a problem if two cities are connected with each other because you will get double edges. Instead use a variable to store it somewhere in you graph class, in your example
   `double startingForce = 120;`
2. Your call in relax switches between remaining forces and casualties the wrong way around. For calling formula you need your remaining forces, but the output needs to be transformed to casualties again.

   ```
   double casualtiesWithCurrentPath = startingForce - formula(startingForce - d.get(u), e.getWeight());
   if (casualtiesWithCurrentPath < d.get(v))
       d.put(v, casualtiesWithCurrentPath);
   ```
3. If a node is unreachable it has `infinity` casualties, leading to `-infinity` remaining forces in this node. However by squaring them in `formula` the sign gets lost, leading to infinite strength, so you need to calculate with

   ```
   double a = Math.signum(ourCity) * Math.pow(ourCity, 2);
   ```

   instead

With these changes I get `{a=13.229217479686895, b=17.043698590130006, c=11.372195087997852, d=12.761947052363922, e=4.241630972097752, f=0.41739256898601695, g=1.678404338007681, h=0.0}` in the example

Comment: Thanks! For this graph: https://i.imgur.com/HPSRDny.png (in circles are armies, above the circles are results that the square law is supposed to output, A is the starting vertex), it outputs these results: {J=87.03851860318429, K=88.21017387744841, A=0.0, H=54.13062023528114, C=40.0, G=62.06584652321869, E=59.207843891257724, D=3.025776620794744, B=0.9848496441074985, I=67.76647707742761, F=7.782864932811975, L=87.03851860318429}, which isn't correct (see numbers above the circles for correct answers). However, with your changes, I feel like I am now so close! Could you please help? Thanks

Comment: The numbers above seem correct. They are the casualties, so in order to get the remaining strength you need to subtract them from your initial strength before outputing.
But since the algorithm is minimizing casualties it is important the nodes are weighted with the casualties, not the remaining strength

Comment: Oh, sorry, I feel dumb now.. So it works now, thank you very much. I was stuck on this problem for the last week..